# PHP interface: specify a parameter list, but not the parameter type

Tags: php, interface, parameters

I've created an interface called `iMapper`. And I want all my mappers file to implement that interface.

But each mapper will specify the parameter type.

Example:

```
interface iMapper
{
    public function insert($obj);
    public function update($obj);
    public function delete($obj);
}
class CarMapper implements iMapper
{
    public function insert(Car $obj){}
    public function update(Car $obj){}
    public function delete(Car $obj){}
}
```

That code generate the following error:

> Declaration of CarMapper::insert() must be compatible with that of iMapper::insert()

Is their a way of making the interface compatible with the `CarMapper`? (I don't want to change the mapper.)

Thanks

Comment: I made update to my answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"But each mapper will specify the parameter type." - I have to say that can't be done.

Interface must be implemented. What does it mean? That all implementing classes will have to be able to use methods with **not specified** parameter - parameter that was required by method inside interface.

calling `instanceof` inside method body is some kind of way out, but it's realy not a good way.

Read about **strategy pattern**, I bet it can solve your problem - http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/strategy/php

Comment: That sound totally ridiculous to my ears, but as the question was more about the feasibility and not about how the actual behavior is, I think that's the best anwser. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

better:

```
interface iObject {}

class Car implements iObject

interface iMapper
{
    public function insert(iObject $obj);
    public function update(iObject $obj);
    public function delete(iObject $obj);
}
class CarMapper implements iMapper
{
    public function insert(Car $obj){}
    public function update(Car $obj){}
    public function delete(Car $obj){}
}
```

Comment: better so that the arguments of the interface methods iMapper can take any object implementing interface iObject (not only the object Car)

Comment: Looks tempting but it won't work, because implementation MUST be compatible with declared interface. So instead of CarMapper::insert(Car) it has to be implemented as CarMapper::insert(iObject).

Answer (score 0):

```
interface iMapper
{
    public function insert(Car $obj);
    public function update(Car $obj);
    public function delete(Car $obj);
}
class CarMapper implements iMapper
{
    public function insert(Car $obj){}
    public function update(Car $obj){}
    public function delete(Car $obj){}
}
```

interface and class methods must match! Same type hinting must be used.

Comment: Maybe you're right, but that code doesn't help me much. What's the point of creating 1 interface per object ? I want 1 interface to be use by many objects...

Answer (score 0):

Your class has to implement the interface. But it doesn't so PHP complains.

You might use type checking within the methods.

Have a look at [instanceof](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.type.php).